# error-code in web.xml not working

Tags: web.xml, jboss6.x, error-code

application running `JBoss6.1.0 final`. For error handling `<error-page>` is used in `web.xml`.

My web.xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <FILTERS>
    <SERVLETS>
    <SERVLET-MAPPINGS>
    .
    .
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>error_500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error_404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

for code 404 its working as excepted. But for 500 its not working, So I have tried

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>error_500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and other exception also not working.

Is I am doing anything wrong, any other to face same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you bundled correctly the specified error pages in your web application?
For example, check the following sample:

```
myapp.war
 |
 |- META-INF
 |- WEB-INF
 |     |    
 |     |- web.xml
 |     |- jboss-web.xml
 |
 |- error_500.jsp
```

And here is the corresponding excerpt from the web.xml file:

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>500</error-code>
   <location>/error_500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Also note that Internet Explorer does not display error pages or messages with a content size smaller than 512 bytes. Be sure that the error pages you use, have a resulting response bodies larger than 512 bytes to ensure all browsers display it.

Comment: Yes jsp's are appropriate place. Its working for 404, Issue is with 500.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring  diferently for 500 and 404 errors:

```
<location>error_500.jsp</location>  
<location>/error_404.jsp</location>
```

On error 500 you missed the / character.